# Is Puma better than Unicorn for Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn, puma

There is a lot of talk about Puma and how it is faster than Unicorn. But, they also mention that it is more suitable for instances of JRuby and Rubinius.

MY question: What about a Rails 3.2 app with Ruby 1.9.3? Unicorn or Puma?

Comment: Stack has got to change it's policy on opinionated questions. Because more often than not, they provide answers that guide the decisions made by NOOBS like me.

Comment: What happened to my previous comment? I'm gonna take a deeper look into this over next couple of days and hope to be able to write useful answer. Hope you can wait until then

Comment: You know with Puma you are going to need to enable config.threadsafe and that is quite a can of worms.. But it is something everyone needs to look at considering it is enabled by default in Rails 4.

Comment: I'm running Rails 4 so no problem for me